# trying to add an extra string to this tooltip but do not know how to add a line space

Tags: javascript, svg

I am working with the plugin SVGA USA Map from: http://codecanyon.net/item/interactive-svg-usa-map/1021095.
I am able to add the extra string but it is appended right next to the state name like so:
AlabamaextraString when i want it to appear like this:
Alabama
extraString

here is the code i playing with i figured their is an easy way of doing this but i am just not thinking of it. directJobs[id] is the extra string i am adding by appending it.
Please any help would be greatly appreciated. i don't have access to ask the author as of right now.

```
    $('#map').next('.point').remove();
    $('#map').after($('<div />').addClass('point'));
    $('.point').html(stateNames[id]).css({
          left: mouseX - 50,
          top: mouseY - 70
    }).append(directJobs[id]).fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending the directJobs[id] string to stateNames[id] with no other characters separating the two. Something like this should work:

```
$('#map').next('.point').remove();
$('#map').after($('<div />').addClass('point'));
$('.point').html(stateNames[id]).css({
      left: mouseX - 50,
      top: mouseY - 70
}).append("&nbsp;" + directJobs[id]).fadeIn();
```

Comment: that works, but how would i make it drop down a line space instead of just adding a space? thanks for your help by the way